# How do I get the media attachment data at Hangouts Chat Bot?

Tags: chatbot, google-hangouts

I want to get the information about a media (image) that was sent to my google Hangouts Chat bot.

Here's the message payload when I send an image to the bot. There's none image info at all.

```
{
  "name": "spaces/3IF_ggAAAAE/messages/HDdTfXFSVUI.HDdTfXFSVUI",
  "sender": {
    "name": "users/108185132749860353654",
    "displayName": "Eduardo Cauli",
    "type": "HUMAN"
  },
  "text": "",
  "cards": [],
  "previewText": "",
  "annotations": [],
  "thread": {
    "name": "spaces/3IF_ggAAAAE/threads/HDdTfXFSVUI"
  },
  "space": {
    "name": "spaces/3IF_ggAAAAE",
    "type": "DM",
    "displayName": ""
  },
  "fallbackText": "",
  "argumentText": "",
  "createTime": "2019-05-13T18:24:50.712303Z"
}
```

Comment: Did you get to find the solution for this?